# Using reinterpret_cast to return long long from char*

Tags: c++, bit, reinterpret-cast

I have the following code:

```
char* p = "12345";

long long x = *reinterpret_cast<long long*>(p);
```

and I keep getting 228509037105 for `x`- I was expecting 12345.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

I asked the question wrongly due to my initial understanding. However, from what I have been later told it is possible to read 8 bytes from a char array using `reinterpret_cast`! After all, whether bits constitute towards a value or a pointer, they are the same thing at bit-level!

Comment: That's not how `reinterpret_cast` works at all. See a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Nearly all through question, just about none in the C and C++ tags though...

Answer (score 4):

A `reinterpret_cast` of pointers forces the compiler to **reinterpret** the memory address in a different data type. To convert the string `"12345"` to a long long `12345` you need to convert the number:

```
#include <sstream>

long long str2ll(const char* p) {
    std::sstream ss;
    ss << p;
    long long r;
    ss >> r;
    return r;
}
```

As chris on the comments says, in C++11 you can use [`std::stoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
const char* p = "12345";
long long n = std::stoll(std::string(p));
```

**Update**: You *can* read a `long long` from 8 bytes of memory, but the string "12345678" reinterpreted as a `long long` pointer won't be the integer "12345678" but dependent on the [endianess of your architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness):

```
const char* p = "12345678";
long long n = *reinterpret_cast<const long long*>(p);
std::cout << n << std::endl;
```

This program prints `4050765991979987505` or `3544952156018063160`, whether you are on a little or big endian architecture. And that's because:

```
hex(4050765991979987505) = 0x38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31
hex(3544952156018063160) = 0x31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
```

`0x38` is the hex representation of the ASCII digit `8`.

Comment: Ok I was slightly mistaken in my understanding and therefore the way I asked the Q, BUT you can still use reinterpret_cast to read 8 bytes, from a char* (so I have been told)....

Comment: @user997112 Sure, you *can* read 8 bytes with reinterpret_cast, the issue is how you interpret them. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding the usage of reinterpret_cast. Please [read this documentation page for reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

What your function does is as follows:
The line `char* p = "12345";` creates a pointer-to-char variable named `p`, which points to a memory region containing a constant buffer initialized with the 6 bytes `\0x31\0x32\0x33\0x34\0x35\0x00`. When you would pass this variable p to, for example, printf, it would interpret the memory pointed to by `p` as a null-terminated string, and print "12345".

The line `long long x = *reinterpret_cast<long long*>(p);` creates a temporary pointer-to-long-long initialized with the value of p, meaning it points to the same memory region as p (this is actually undefined behaviour as per case 6 in the link above), then dereferences it and assigns the value to `x`. Because `long long` is usually 8 bytes long, and p only points to 6 valid bytes, this dereference is again undefined behaviour, but you are getting 228509037105 (binary 0x3534333231), which means your machine is little-endian and the extra 2 bytes are also 0.

If you want to get `x == 12345`, the correct way to do it is `long long x = std::stoll(p)`.

You are also misunderstanding the fact that "However, from what I have been later told it is possible to read 8 bytes from a char array using reinterpret_cast". 
What you can do, is convert a `char*` value to a `long long` value, assuming `sizeof void*` is not larger than `sizeof(long long)` on your machine (see case 2 in the link above). If `sizeof void*` equals 8, then you are "reading 8 bytes from a 'char array'(actually from a pointer-to-char) :
`long long x = reinterpret_cast<long long>(p)`. This gives you the address which p originally contained, stored as a `long long` value in the variable x. Anything you do with this value, except casting it back to `char*`, is undefined behaviour. 
You can do, for example, `printf(reinterpret_cast<char*>(x))`, which will print your original char buffer "12345".

Answer (score 0):

The underlying bytes are `0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34 and 0x35` for the ascii values of `1,2,3,4 and 5`.  Take the value you received and convert it to hex and you'll see what i'm talking about.

reinterpret_cast is generally used to convert between pointer types or to another integral type.  For example, you could convert a pointer to a number and then use sprintf to output the value using one of the integer format specifiers instead of the pointer specifier

Comment: You would use an implicit conversion from `char *` to `void *`, and `static_cast` for the other way. In my experiences, I've used `reinterpret_cast` for things like [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx) where you could be passing a pointer to something that takes an integral type.